# /etc/bash.bashrc equivalent for sh

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, docker, alpine-linux

I know about the differences between `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, and `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Other than `/etc/profile`, these are all specific to the `bash` shell.

I would like to have a script run every time I open, as any user, a **non-login** (interactive or non-interactive) shell, but not for `bash`, for `sh`. My objective is to have a script that runs every time I `docker exec ... /bin/sh` into an Alpine Linux container. This container does not have `bash`.

Is there any such global configuration file for `sh`? If there isn't, is it possible to emulate this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior of `sh` is specified by POSIX.  A Linux system may have a variety of shells which are used as `/bin/sh`, including but not limited to bash, dash, mksh, or ash, and while each of these may have custom mechanisms for implementing behavior in this case, the only thing you can rely on across all of them is what POSIX specifies.

The way to specify a configuration file for interactive use with `sh` is to set the `ENV` environment variable to the name of that file.  Beyond that, POSIX doesn't provide a standard file for non-login shells.  The text from POSIX is as follows:

> This variable, when and only when an interactive shell is invoked, shall be subjected to parameter expansion (see Parameter Expansion) by the shell, and the resulting value shall be used as a pathname of a file containing shell commands to execute in the current environment. The file need not be executable. If the expanded value of `ENV` is not an absolute pathname, the results are unspecified. `ENV` shall be ignored if the real and effective user IDs or real and effective group IDs of the process are different.

If you need commands for a non-interactive shell, you'll need to provide them as arguments on the command line.

Comment: Ok, thanks! The `$ENV` strategy sounds like it should work great, but how can I set that to my script path so it's already there when I start the shell? As far as I know, the only way to do that is in `.bashrc` or equivalent, and that would kind of defeat my purpose here, since I would have to set it manually every time.

Comment: `docker exec -e ENV=/my/path/in/container /bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. +1